# different pages loading into div with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to  load three different html files into a div, one after the other, with a delay of 5 seconds. After it cycles through all three I want it to carry on repeating. I tried using timeout to do this but its still not working.Any help would be appreciated.. code snippet below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery(window).load (function timeout() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if($("#news_sections").hasClass("news1")){
                    $("#news_sections").attr('class', "news2");
                    $( "#news_sections" ).load( "section2.html" );
                }else if($("#news_sections").hasClass("news2")){
                    $("#news_sections").attr('class', 'news3');
                    $( "#news_sections" ).load( "section3.html" );
                }else{
                    $("#news_sections").attr('class', 'news1');
                    $( "#news_sections" ).load( "section1.html" );
                };

                timeout();

            }, 4000);
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is your html file path correct? and, why do you have both document ready and window load function?

Comment: What exactly is not working? What goes wrong? It looks like you've got an extra `});` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, instead of changing classes and depending on them.

In case you have more than 10 `sectionX.html` files, you will need to write a lot of code there. So if you make an counter, you have to change only the `if` statement to `(count > X)` where X = number of templates you have.

```
var count = 1;

setInterval(function () {
  // If the count is more 3, we reset the count to 1.
  if (count > 3) {
    count = 1;
  }

  // If you are using "newsX" class for looping propose only,
  // You can remove .attr() method in my solution. 
  $("#news_sections").attr('class', "news" + count);

  // clear news section
  $("#news_sections").empty();

  // Load the count number sectionX.html file
  // Also increase count number with 1 (count++)
  $("#news_sections").load( "section" + count++ + ".html" );

}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested but you should do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var curIdx = 0, /* internal counter */
        urls   = ['page1.html','page2.html','page3.html'], /* your urls*/
        doCache = true, /* set to false to disable caching */
        cache  = {} /* storage */;
    function nextPage(){
        var data = false, 
            url  = urls[curIdx];
        if(doCache && cache[url]) {
            data = cache[url];
        }
        curIdx += 1; 
        // all urls displayed - reset counter, show first page again
        if(curIdx == urls.length) {
            curIdx = 0;
        }            
        // load data (and cache it, if doCached option is true)
        if(!data){
            $("#content").load(url, function(data){
                cache[url] = data;
                nextTimer();
            })
        } else {
            $("#content").html(data);
            nextTimer();
        }
    };
    // now to timeout
    function nextTimer(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){ nextPage() }, 5000); // 5 Seconds
    }
    // and run it...
    nextPage();
});
```

Be aware that this might not work with external urls.

Comment: It's good advanced solution. I actually like it, but I think that the question owner will confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit convoluted, and you should probably not use setTimeout like that. I believe what you're looking for is [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), which executes the same function repeatedly, every X milliseconds.

I simplified it a bit. First, declare the `loopNews()` function, and then set the timeout call when the document is ready.

```
function loopNews(){
    if($("#news_sections").hasClass("news1")){
        $("#news_sections").attr('class', "news2");
        $("#news_sections").load( "section2.html" );
    }else if($("#news_sections").hasClass("news2")){
        $("#news_sections").attr('class', 'news3');
        $("#news_sections").load( "section3.html" );
    }else{
        $("#news_sections").attr('class', 'news1');
        $("#news_sections").load( "section1.html" );
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(loopNews, 5000);
});
```